# Iterating the Voter protocol

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability

Assume you have an array of length $n$ filled with the numbers $1,2,...,n$. (Actually, it only matters that all numbers are different.) This corresponds to a Dirac delta distribution for the number prevalency. Now, synchroneously, all slots of the array choose a uniform random other slot (this includes choosing itself or duplicates) and take this as new value. You get a Poisson distribution (with $\mu=1$) for the prevalency. Rinse and repeat (this is the Voter protocol) until you converged to consensus (another Dirac delta).
Since there is a mass of literature on this protocol, I drowned in references (mainly dealing with runtime and such) but was not able to find one giving an analytic formula for the distributions that come after the Poisson. Can you help me out? (Or solve the one after the Poisson in your head? :-)

EDIT: To make clearer how the process runs, here is an example for $n=4$. $ABCD[abcd]$ means that slot $1$, having opinion $A$, "asks" slot $a$ for his opinion, and so on. Votes drawn from the hat :-)
$1234 [2133]\rightarrow 2133[4322] \rightarrow 3311[1114] \rightarrow 3331[2112] \rightarrow 3333$, stop.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think there *is* a closed form expression?

Comment: It matters how "choose" is implemented. Say k less than n slots receive votes after round 1. Are there n voters for round 2, or just k many voters?  Also, if slots 1 and 2 vote for slot 7 in round 1, must their votes agree in all later rounds?  Gerhard "Voting Is A Tricky Business" Paseman, 2018.03.21.

Comment: @Nate: Not at all! I did a lot of simulations. With a Best-2-of-3 voting rule (which is something quite different!) the "lower" side of the distribution looks like an exponential distribution (which is quite useless, as those votes are on death row in the next steps anyway), so I won't exclude it for the $n=\infty$ case either.

Comment: @Gerhard: So true. I will edit in an example that makes it clearer.

Comment: (Addendum: Also for this rule, the distribution after only 10% of the opinions remain is approximately exponential, except at 0, the extinct opinions. I just simulated it. After only 1% remain, it's already very jagged but you can still recognize it, so yes, I conjecture that an infinite exponential distribution is invariant under this rule. Of course, for a realistic problem this would still be useless. I took $n=10^6$.)